# Intersection(s) of 3 hyperboloids

Tags: geometry

I have four focus points: $F1$, $F2$, $F3$ and $F4$.
There are also some other known variables: $a$, $b$ and $c$

There are three hyperboloid functions defined:
$h1(P) = |P-F1|-|P-F2| - 2a = 0$
$h2(P) = |P-F1|-|P-F3| - 2b = 0$
$h3(P) = |P-F1|-|P-F4| - 2c = 0$

These functions say that for any point P, if the result is 0, the point P lies on the surface of the hyperboloid.

I want to find the point(s) of intersection between the three given functions.
[image: Image overview of the problem]

Comment: Please, cite your sources http://inspirehep.net/record/1408266/plots

Comment: There are two kinds of hyperboloids : hyperboloid of one sheet, and hyperboloid of 2 sheets. Here, it is the latter. Be conscious that his figure shows only 3 of the 6 sheets of these hyperboloids of 2 sheets ; let us call them "dishes". I understand that among each pair of dishes you choose the dish that has reference point $F_1$ inside its concavity.

Comment: I did link the image to the source, but apparently that was converted to imgur... Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

This can be iteratively solved like this:

A 4D surface is defined as all $(x,y,z)$ points with an extra $w$ component.
For every $(x,y,z)$ the value of $w$ is $|h1(x,y,z)| + |h2(x,y,z)| + |h3(x,y,z)|$.

With this surface, any $(x,y,z)$ point can be chosen. Then iteratively move the point in a direction that has a lower $w$ value. This may be seen as rolling a ball down a hill, but in 4D.

When the point is at an $(x,y,z)$ coordinate where the $w$ is $0$, then that is a point where the hyperboloids intersect.

This solution won't find you all the intersections though, just one.